# new-using block with remove-itemversion

Tags: powershell-extensions

While learning about Remove-ItemVersion, I came across below piece of code -

```
New-UsingBlock(New-Object Sitecore.Data.Events.EventDisabler) {
    Remove-ItemVersion -Path master:\content\home -Language "en" -MaxRecentVersions 10
}
```

Can anybody please tell me why is new-usingblock used here with remove-itemversion?
Is it necessary to use it everytime we are working with Remove-ItemVersion?

Comment: The command is run in the context of an event disabler. Typically any event subscription due to removing a version will not be fired.

Answer (score 1):

`New-UsingBlock` is analogous to the `using` block we use in C#.

As per the definition in [Sitecore PowerShell Doc](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/new-usingblock), The `New-UsingBlock` command disposes of the provided input object after the specified scriptblock completes execution. You may find the data returned by the scriptblock is contained within the following object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection1[[System.Management.Automation.PSObject, System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]`. This helps when multiple objects are returned and is known behavior.

Like `using`block in C#, it is not mandatory to use `New-UsingBlock` but a best practice as it takes care of disposing objects that are no longer needed after the script is executed. Generally, this is very useful when dealing with bulk operations where lot of objects are created at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The `New-UsingBlock` command disposes of the provided input object after the specified scriptblock completes execution. So if the type implements `IDisposable`, it automatically disposes it. It is similar to the `using`, let's understand it in simple c# way -

```
public class ADisposableClass : IDisposable
{
   //Some class implementation
}
```

In the above class, we want to call the `dispose()` every time, even if the code throws an exception -

```
ADisposableClass aDisposableClass = new ADisposableClass ();
try
{
  aDisposableClass .Action();
}
finally
{
  if (aDisposableClass != null)
    aDisposableClass .Dispose();
}
```

and another method is to use the `using` block -

```
using (ADisposableClass aDisposableClass = new ADisposableClass ()) {
aDisposableClass.Action();
}
```

In your piece of code- `New-UsingBlock(New-Object Sitecore.Data.Events.EventDisabler)`, `EventDisabler` is being called during Remove-ItemVersion. A script execution triggers some events in the background and if you don't want to trigger those events then you can simply use the `EventDisabler` in using statement. once you wrap something with `New-UsingBlock` statement, everything that is inside should work in 'switched context', with all events disabled.

Most of your questions are related to Sitecore Powershell Extension, I will suggest you, walk through the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) module documents- https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com

Comment: Hi, I have read SPE documents. But some of my doubts that doesn't get clear, those I post here.